# How to run map reduce program from windows using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I have installed Eclipse in windows system and my hadoop cluster is on CentOs server machines. I've used CDH5.3 for my cluster. 
So how can i run eclipse with hadoop eclipse plugin on windows machine?

I am not able to figure out how I can run map reduce programs from this windows machine to the hadoop master node.

Any idea how to do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All the nodes in Hadoop - master nodes, slave nodes and including Client should have same hadoop distribution. Client in this case is your machine, you should also be using Cent OS and same Hadoop distribution.